# How to list RPM packages installed in order of installation date

Tags: linux, fedora, rhel, yum, rpm

I'd like to see a list of software installed in the order of the date they were installed. The order doesn't matter (newest to oldest & vice-versa) as long as they're arranged by date.

I'm mainly interested in seeing what libraries I've installed. Since I've installed so many, I need to know what libraries were installed together so that I may recall what software required these, if I need to do a fresh installation.

I'm using Fedora 16 w/ the yum.

Comment: Have you looked at the manuals for `rpm` or `yum`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Fortunately rpm does offer this itself:

```
rpm -qa --last
```

or if you can limit the packages by name

```
rpm -qa --last 'lib*' 'morelibs*'
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to see transactions, and not just packages, you might want to look at "yum history" instead.

Note that you can "export" the transactions with:

```
yum history addon-info last saved_tx
```

...where you can replace "last" with the transaction ID of any older transaction, if you want. You can then feed those transactions into:

```
yum load-transaction
```